# Can two drupal distributions co exist?

Tags: 7, distributions

I am working on a drupal site and One of the functionality of my site is to have an [ideation platform](http://drupal.org/project/idea). Can I make a distribution work seamlessly within my drupal instance ?

Comment: What a great wish!  +1 for your nice idea. I would add it as an important feature request for future drupal version.

Answer (score 3):

*Seamlessly*, probably not. However, what may work is to merge your own Drupal site's install profile with the code found in [`idea.install`](http://drupalcode.org/project/idea.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/idea.install). Additionally, you'll want to enable all of the modules found [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/idea.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/modules).

Comment: Can I use the same login database for two different distributions ?

Comment: Yes, of course, it's the same database. And you will probably have to make some adjustments and testing. Ususally, I won't expect it to work out of the box.