# Using the Panopoly and Commerce Kickstart distributions together

Tags: commerce, distributions

I want to create an e-commerce site, and also have the ability to easily create landing pages, using the wonderful responsive layouts of the panopoly landing page editor.

What is the easiest way to go?

1. Install panopoly on top of commerce kickstart distribution?
2. Install commerce modules on top of the panopoly distribution?
3. [Edit the distrubtion makefile](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51880/can-two-drupal-distributions-co-exist) - like someone did with other distributions.

How to do it successfully? And did somebody do it?

Comment: @Drupvision can you share your experience with this? I'm in the same situation right now. –

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do #2.  To my knowledge, all of the modules in Commerce Kickstart can be downloaded separately; Commerce Kickstart just offers some default configurations.  If you run into trouble setting up the Commerce modules, you can always install a copy of Commerce Kickstart on a local machine/another server and reference that while you are setting up your main site.

By contrast, the problem with #1 is that not all of Panoply is easily configurable if you are not using that distribution (for example, the responsive layouts).  So it will be much easier to use that, especially if you are going to host it on Pantheon, which is behind Panoply.

You could edit the distribution makefile but that is probably more trouble than it's worth; the Commerce modules are designed to be installed on any Drupal site, so adding them to Panoply is very straightforward.

Comment: This is definitely the best way round. @druvision Panopoly has some issues (it's only in RC at the moment), I wouldn't recommend it for a live site having used it recently

Comment: I agree with this advice.
Commerce Kickstart includes custom themes and many contribs and Commerce contribs, but each piece is available separately.

Comment: @Clive would you still say the same now in october about Panopoly ? I imagine this project is finished now, could you make a short feedback about installing commerce on top of Panopoly ? I'm about to do exactly the same... Thanks

Comment: Druvision, could you please make a short feedback about installing commerce on top of Panopoly, and usability of Panopoly for custom e-commerce if you did so ? I would be very grateful

Comment: @Drupvision can you share your experience with this? I'm in the same situation right now.